# How can I filter the result of a query based on restrictions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, filter

I have a problem with a dynamically generated SQL query. I have a HUGE database where users are stored in different tables. I need to dynamically create a query which will return me the user_id-s based on some restrictions with different partitioning. So far i created a logic which will create me the query based on the restrictions, but I can't figure it out how could I filter the result to have different partitioning. 
For example:

**I have the following:**

1: Male
2: Female
3: Age between 18-24
4: Age between 25-99
5: Working at IBM
Lets say i have 50k female, 50k male

Now if my restriction is (1 or 2) and 5, which translates to if it's a male or female working at IBM, I generated something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id from usertable1 where age in (0,1) 
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT user_id from usertable2 where work_place = 'IBM'
```

Now my problem is that this isn't enough, there are times when i have to partition the resulting set of user ids like so  for example that I have 33% male and 66% female in the result list. I don't know how to get it properly. I tried to count how many female and male user I have, then apply a top to them, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  top 25000 user_id from usertable1 where age in (0)
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT top 50000  user_id from usertable1 where age in (1)
SELECT DISTINCT user_id from usertable2 where work_place = 'IBM'
```

However this isn't giving me the right solution, the problem with this is that if I have no female user working at IBM in my list this will return 25k male and 0 female, which is not 33% male and 66% female...

Now to complicate it even more, I can have even harder partitioning like so that the result must contain 33% male from which 75& percent is age between 18-24 and 25& age between 25-99 and 66% female from which 75& percent is age between 18-24 and 25& age

**So my problem is that i have no idea how to solve both of the problem, which can work on huge database, 50k male and 50k female is small compared to the full database. Anyone have any idea for at least one of my problem?**

**EDIT 1:**
My table has a bit strange structure, it's more like a link table. To simplify it and to show my problem, lets consider this example table which has similar format of mine.
I have user_id, question, question_answer, age, gender. The same user_id appears multiple time as this is only a link table and a user mostly answers for multiple question. The structure of this is by far not optimal i know, but it wasn't designed by me, nor can be modified by me. My task is to get the distinct user_id's which completes all the restriction and filter the result to have percentage partitioning based on another restriction set. So far I got the correct user_id's based on the restriction, but i have no idea how can i modify this to be able have percentage partitioning.

So, to be more precise, i have a restriction set which can be something like (1 OR 2) AND 3 AND 4 so on. I create a reverse polish form from this to be able to solve it in order. Based on every restriction (for example be male, age between 18-24) I create quires which I then concatenate with union or intersect. This work well as long as i don't need to partition it. But unfortunately that's the case and because my result doesn't contain any detail about the answered questions, nor age nor gender only the user_id, i have no idea how could i modify it, to be able to filter the result to have the wanted partition sizes by percentage.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. Are you trying to return a *random sample* from a larger superset of records, where the selected sample fits a certain distribution?

Comment: I need to return user_id-s based on some restrictions with some given partition. So i need to return for example male or female user who works at IBM, but the returned list of user_id-s have to match the partition size( 33% percent male and 66%) female

Comment: I edited the post, hope it makes more sense like this.

Comment: And what if, for example, IBM employs 50% male of 100 workers? Would you want it to return 50 females and 25 males (if so, *which* males?)? 6 females and 3 males (again this fits your partitioning) (again *which* rows)? Zero rows because the partition does not match? Something else?

Comment: Yes, if IBM has 100 workers of which 50% male, and my partition settings is 33% male and 66% female, i want it to return 50 female and 25 male. So basically i want the maximum available number of users which fits both the restriction and partition.

Comment: And which males do you want?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, the ones the query returns, the only thing matters that it has to fulfill the restrictions and the partitions should match

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+ you can use `TOP(x)PERCENT`

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT TOP(5)PERCENT JobTitle, HireDate
FROM HumanResources.Employee
ORDER BY HireDate DESC;
```

Taken from [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Just read the rest of your post but you should be able to solve your second problem using CTE's and chain them together. That would give you say 70% of something that feeds into your second CTE where you take 40% of the 70% and so on.

Comment: This isn't good for me, with this i would get 5% of the total results in the table. My task is to get as much users as possible with given restriction and filter them according to partition restriction. For example get as much employee working for IT, but the result set needs to be filtered so it would contain for example twice as much female then male.

Comment: It's still not clear for me. I have a complex restriction which at the moment only returns user_ids, so at this form i have no way of differentiate them based on partition... I'll update the question so it would be more clear

Comment: So it sounds to me like you need to build it from the bottom. Add your restrictions to get you a population you can then segment. Split it into smaller tasks and build a few temp tables along the way. Sounds like a good piece of work. Good luck :-)

Comment: Well i have an idea if I change the way I parse the restriction, i could split it up and union them as such, now my only problem is that at the moment I have no idea how to do it... I never liked polish form and stuff... The idea is to remove parentheses an make query based on that. So for example the (1 OR 2) AND 3 would be modified to have 1 AND 3 OR 2 AND 3, make two queries based on it 1 and 3, count it, 2 AND 3 count it, then make a top select form these two and union it